# Flatten json in Python from XHR-response

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest, flatten

Updated: The XHR response was not correct earlier

I'm failing with flatten my json in a correct way from a XHR-response.
I have just expanded one item below, to make it more readable.

I am using python and I have tried, with incorrect outcome.

```
u = "URL"
SE_units = requests.get(u,headers=h).json()
dp = pd.json_normalize(SE_units,[SE_units,"Items"])
SE_dp_list.append(dp)
```

From the XHR-Response below I would like to have the Items-information into a CSV but when i do export.to_CSV I see that it haven't been flattened correctly

```
{"Content":{
"PaginationCount":12,"FilterValues":null,"Items":
[{
    "Id":258370,
    "OriginalType":"BostadObjectPage",
    "PublishDate":null,
    "Title":"02 Skogsvagen",
    "Image":
    {
        "description":null,
        "alt":null,
        "externalUrl":"/abc.jpg"
    },
    "StaticMapImage":null,
    "Url":"/abcd/",
    "HideReadMore":false,
    "ProjectData":null,
    "ObjectData":
    {
        "BuildingTypeLabel":"Rad-/Kedje-/Parhus",
        "ObjectStatus":"SalesInProgress",
        "ObjectStatusLabel":"Till salu",
        "ObjectNumber":"02",
        "City":"staden",
        "RoomInterval":"2-3",
        "LivingArea":"101",
        "SalesPrice":"2 150 000",
        "MonthlyFee":null,
        "Elevator":false,
        "Balcony":false,
        "Terrace":true
    },
    "FastighetProjectData":null,
    "FastighetObjectData":null,
    "OfficeData":null
},
{
    "Id":258372,
    "OriginalType":"BostadObjectPage",
    "PublishDate":null,
    ....."same structure as above"
    "OfficeData":null
}],
"NoResultsMessage":null,
"SimplifiedBuildingType":null,
"NextIndex":-1,
"TotalCount":12,
"Heading":null,
"ShowMoreLabel":null,
"DataColumns":null,
"Error":null},
"ObjectSearchData":
{
    "BuildingVariantId":"Houses",
    "BuildingsFoundLabel":" {count}",
    "BuildingTypeIds":[400],
    "BuildingsAvailableForSale":12,
    "BuildingNoResultsLabel":""
}
```

}

Expected output format after writing to CSV
[image]

Comment: What's the original response and your expected result?

Comment: What do you mean with original response? I can create an example of expected result in a table and insert. Give me a couple of minutes. Should have added that of course to be clear. But I want it to be fully flattened under "Items".

Comment: are you removing things here? Items: [,…] it's making it difficult to get you an answer. but it looks like you need ['Content']['Items']. If json_normalize doesn't flatten it enough you can look into flatten_json which works very well for deeply nested json structures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jonathan. I see now that my cut and paste from the inspect tab in the browser didn't got the response correctly. I have updated the code above now and I hope it is more clear. Any suggestion on how to flattern it on "items"?

Comment: `json_normalize()` will not expand embedded lists without using optional params.  you need to consider how you want to deal with these

Comment: Thanks Rob! Any suggestion on how I can proceed or solve it? It is only the items information which is of relevance for me. I don't necessarily have to use json_normalize if there are better solutions.